# How to reduce the risk of user-generated functions that are run on the backend (eval())

Tags: javascript, node.js, docker, eval

## How to reduce risks of user-generated functions that are executed in a Docker container that is used exclusively by the users who wrote the functions?

I am working on a platform that allows users to create very customized CRMs. Users declare what the CRM should look like and the system "builds" the CRM based on that individual declaration. Everything is hosted in the cloud and for each client, there is an own Docker container where their customized CRM runs on NodeJS. Until now the configuration is basically a key-value table with strictly sanitized input.

However, now, I need to allow users to add own functions written by the users themselves that shall be executed upon one of many events the users can choose (e.g. onEmailDelivered, onNewRecord, onLogin, etc). These functions must have sometimes access to the CRMs data and functions otherwise they don't make sense.

#### **How can I allow for that kind of customization (user-generated functions) with the least possible (intentional or unintentional) danger?**

Running the functions as JS with eval() on the client-side in order to limit the risk of malicious or buggy code is not an option for various reasons. Among which is the fact that many of the events that trigger these functions are registered by the backend only (cronjobs, webhooks, incoming emails, and many more) and other reasons.

I have thought of 3 approaches:

#### **Option 1: Check all user-generated functions manually before admitting them to be run by the backend.**

- Labor-intensive process, hard to scale, and at the end still prone to human error + bad user experience having to wait each time for approval.

#### **Option 2: Accepting the risks knowing that the user is responsible for the functions they upload since they will be executed in their container where only their CRM resides.**

- I know users could still unintentionally cause damage to their own data, but what about risks to other parties?
- Q: Is there a way I can programmatically or by means of special backend configuration make 100% sure that these functions can not harm anything outside of their container e.g. accessing other Containers or the Host OS?

#### **Option 3: Programmatically check user-generated functions for undesired behavior before admitting them.**

- In this approach: What technologies can I use to limit the scope of what the function can do? E.g.: No deletion of important data, No blocking, No calls to external IPs, No exec commands, no accessing filesystem, only using a limited set of JS functions, etc.

**For Option 3, is there a framework or technology that supports this approach of pre-screening a JS function for certain criteria? **

Also, is there any other way to tackle this problem? I am open to completely new approaches.

Comment: Can these functions be isolated in their own environment? You shouldnt need to be loading them into the same program as the CRM.

Comment: The issue is that they do need to access some of the CRM's functions e.g. ```createNewContact()``` instead of writing directly to the database or ```getLastChangedContact()``` etc

Comment: You can go for option 2 (it's *their* CRM, and they can destroy it however they want), but notice [the security implications of docker containers](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/). Treat them as if they were rogue malicious actors in your network. That includes directly accessing the database with the credentials available to the container.